# how do you count the number of words present in the array below?

Tags: php, arrays

how do you count the number of words present in the array below? is there a php function that can help me solve this problem? or I have to compose my own algorithmic?

```
$array1 = 
[
    'fulan' => 'hadir' ,
    'filan' => 'hadir',
    'folon' => 'hadir'
];

foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {

    similar_text($value, 'hadir', $persen);

    if($persen == 100)
    {

        $data = (array) $value;
        $merge = array_merge($data);
        echo '<pre>';
        echo count($merge);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the output to be?

Comment: I expect results like this

Number of attendance: 3